# Datepicker not working when appending row

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a table where I have two date picker and with the option to append a new row.
The issue is when I add a new row the datepicker is not working.

I created a https://jsfiddle.net/3uhkeq1h/2/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.txtDate22').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
          showButtonPanel: true,

        onClose: function () {
            var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            $(this).datepicker('refresh');
        },

        beforeShow: function () {
            if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            }
        }
    });

    $(".txtDate22").focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
            my: "center top",
            at: "center bottom",
            of: $(this)
        });
    });

    $(".txtDate22").blur(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepicker is not binding for the newly created elements. I have Updated your answer. The only changes that I have done was to put your elements those are in on load, in a separate function and calling them on load as well as on click.

```
function date_picker(){
 $('.txtDate').datepicker({

        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
          showButtonPanel: true,

        onClose: function () {
            var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            $(this).datepicker('refresh');
        },

        beforeShow: function () {
            if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            }
        }
    });
    $('.txtDate22').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
          showButtonPanel: true,

        onClose: function () {
            var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            $(this).datepicker('refresh');
        },

        beforeShow: function () {
            if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So if you want to add similar actions , as your are doing with this, then just add those actions here.

Comment: umm not sure of changes you made ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not calling `datepicker()` for the newly added elements. Even if they are the same class, the function will not be called automatically for elements added to the DOM later.